# Why does increased stock borrow costs decrease a stock's forward price?

Tags: derivatives, forward

The author in this article -- http://streetwiseprofessor.com/?p=7294 -- states that an increase in stock borrowing costs decreases a stock's forward price:

> In the absence of manipulation, the forward price of a stock should be the current spot price plus the cost of financing the position at the prevailing interest rate until the delivery date on the forward.  In the absence of a squeeze, the cost/fee to borrow the stock should be small.  However, in a squeeze, it is costly to borrow the stock: the bigger the squeeze, the bigger the cost of borrowing.  This borrowing cost depresses the forward price.  Thus, during a squeeze, the forward price is below the spot price plus financing costs.

But why? Shouldn't the effect be similar to increased dollar financing rates, namely an *increase* in the forward price?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rate of interest on cash and the cost of borrowing the stock work in opposite directions. Think of the cost of borrowing the stock as a kind of "dividend" that the stock pays off to its holders. As a stock owner you *receive* this amount [if you lend the shares] while you *pay* the interest rate if you hold the stock on margin.